# JHipster Registry - Exception on startup

Tags: jhipster, jhipster-registry

Starting up JHipster Registry throws an exception and it seems to be some sort of nast catch-22 that I cannot resolve.

I imagine that the registry should not register itself, not try to pull its own configuration from the registry (rather that should come from its own environment). To this end, it comes pre-configured like this...

application.yml:

```
eureka:
  client:
    fetch-registry: false
    register-with-eureka: false
```

However, the 'peer' configurations both come with both those values as 'true', and if you turn on the 'uaa' configuration, you turn on eureka.client.fetchRegistry=true.

Now, turning off the 'uaa' profile turns off the exception. Turning it on (because I need it), throws the exception.

```
2020-05-09 03:30:07.759  INFO 7 --- [           main] c.n.d.s.r.aws.ConfigClusterResolver      : Resolving eureka endpoints via configuration                                                 
2020-05-09 03:30:07.814  INFO 7 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Disable delta property : false                                                               
2020-05-09 03:30:07.814  INFO 7 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Single vip registry refresh property : null                                                  
2020-05-09 03:30:07.815  INFO 7 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Force full registry fetch : false                                                            
2020-05-09 03:30:07.815  INFO 7 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Application is null : false                                                                  
2020-05-09 03:30:07.816  INFO 7 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Registered Applications size is zero : true                                                  
2020-05-09 03:30:07.817  INFO 7 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Application version is -1: true                                                              
2020-05-09 03:30:07.818  INFO 7 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Getting all instance registry info from the eureka server                                    
2020-05-09 03:30:08.016 ERROR 7 --- [           main] c.n.d.s.t.d.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient  : Request execution error. endpoint=DefaultEndpoint{ serviceUrl='http://admin:admin@registry.lo


com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)                                                                          
       at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:187)                                                                                    
       at com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.GZIPContentEncodingFilter.handle(GZIPContentEncodingFilter.java:123)                                                                               
       at com.netflix.discovery.EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.handle(EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.java:27)                                                                                         
       at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:652)                                                                                                                            
       at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:682)                                                                                                                  
       at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74)
```

Is there a way out of this?

Comment: Does it cause any issues aside from logging the error during startup? Related discussion: https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-registry/pull/278#discussion_r199327858

Comment: No extra issues. I believe it can be ignored at this time.